# How to measure duty-cycle with Input Capture from STM32F103C8T6?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, duty-cycle, stm32f103c8t6

I'm trying to measure the duty-cycle of the 0-5V electrical PWM signal I have generated from the *any* source. How can I do this? Anyone can help me?

---

- IDE: Keil
- Microcontroller: STM32F103C8T6

Comment: that information belongs in the question  above .... use the edit button to add it, then delete the comment

Answer (score 2):

The process is described in detail in the [Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/cd00171190.pdf), look for **PWM input mode**.

Don't forget to check the input pin in the pin definitions table of the [Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f103cb.pdf). If it's *not* marked as *5 Volt Tolerant* (`FT` in the *I/O Level* column), then place a suitable [voltage divider](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28897/how-to-choose-value-of-resistor-in-voltage-divider) between the signal source and the input pin.

Comment: _berendi_ , I reviewed the article you submitted but I couldn't create enough time to work. Can you share with me if you have code about this situation?

Comment: There are step-by-step instructions in the Reference Manual I've linked. I can't do it any better than that.